# JSCH librairy with signed publickkey

Tags: java, spring, sftp, jsch

I use a public key signed by my client to connect to SFTP. In command line all functions properly.

On the other hand via JSCH Librairy, I have a message error: "Auth fail".

My code is working correctly on another server or the public key is not signed

the jsch version used is the : 0.1.55

my connection setup looks like this

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

jsch.addIdentity(sftpSetting.getPrivateKey());
session = jsch.getSession(sftpSetting.getUser(), sftpSetting.getServer(), sftpSetting.getPort());

session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");

session.connect(sftpSetting.getConnectionTimeout());
// Initializing a channel
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect(sftpSetting.getConnectionTimeout());
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
```

Comment: Not much detail here, Actual Exception stack could help.

Also, Can you try to move the `~/.ssh` folder to a backup and then trying to login with the private key.

Comment: I succeeded my sftp connection by changing the JSCH library by SSHJ.